# Ant base directory up one level

Tags: ant

In ant build, how to specify a directory which is one level up from base directory. I need to do this because I will be calling some libraries common to all projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `..` just as you would use it from the command line (either in Windows or Linux):

```
<property name="parent.dir" location="{base.dir}\.."/>

<target name="jar" description="JAR task" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="yourresource.jar" basedir="${parent.dir}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. This is what I exactly wanted.